# Настройки android-девайса для режима дебаггинга

Tags: unix, ios, android-adb, android

Тестирую возможности [Apportable.](http://www.apportable.com/)

на этапе проверки девайса подключенного к компьютеру предлагается ввести в `Терминале`  каманду:

```
adb devices
```

использую ZTE San Francisco 2, Android  2.3.5, в настройки-приложения разработка-отладка по  usb галка стоит но команда возвращает пустой список. В результате билда `Apportable` все замирает на `waiting for device`  то есть оно его не видит. 
Что нужно еще сделать чтобы девайс был  читаем?

UPDATE 1:
нагуглил что нужно ставить драйвера для устройства но [ссылка](http://sanfranciscoandroid.co.uk/android/how-to-install-the-usb-drivers-for-the-orange-san-francisco-zte-blade-zte-libra-u-v880/) указывает что для этого устройства не нужно устанавливать usb-драйверы. Также [инструкция по сылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7136003/1236726) не помогла решить вопрос.

UPDATE 2:
попробывал подключить девайс от НТС - его система сразу увидела. Есть ли шанс что ZTE это нонейм с которым ничего не получится?

Comment: ИМХО вопрос не имеет отношения к вашему Apportable - вам надо добиться того, чтобы девайс был доступен в режиме отладки. Вы с какого компа соединяетесь? C Win или MacOS?

Comment: использую Mac OS X

Comment: возможно какие то драйверы не установились, можно попробовать установить софт, который идет вместе с телефоном (обычно в него входит менеджер файлов, контактов и т.д)
с ним так же устанавливаются доп драйверы, возможно причина в этом.
по крайней мере мне пару раз именно такой выход из ситуации помог на маке подключить невидимые устройства)

Comment: никаких драйверов в коробке не было, на оф сайте драйвера только для windows, альтернативный источник который я привел в вопросе тоже настаивает что драйверов для макос нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос оказался страшно прост - нужен был нормальный кабель для соединения с компьютером. Как только устройство было подключено по нему, удалось его увидеть и в дальнешем совершить с ним все манипуляции

Answer (score 2):

> использую Mac OS X

Да, [официальная Android дока](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) утверждает, что для Mac OS X не нужны никакие драйвера... Значит проблема в вашем ZTE, тем более что HTC виден.

Comment: спасибо за подтверждение догадки

Comment: Всегда с большим подозрением относился к аппаратам ZTE - теперь буду вдвойне осторожен с этими девайсами, равно как и с т.н. МТСовскими Билайновскими брендированными аппаратами (они почему то все любят ZTE)

Answer (score 2):

Как вы, думаю, знаете, ADB - клиент-серверное приложение, так что убедитесь также на всякий случай, что adb присутствует и на смартфоне ZTE. Не думаю, конечно же, что в ZTE могли так лохонуться со своим San Francisco...а вот Android 2.3 меня( возможно, не только меня ) почему-то смущает. По поводу драйверов. К примеру, из-под Windows изначально у меня тоже не получалось производить отладку с помощью ADB - отсутствовали нужные драйверы. Пришлось долго искать, в конце-концов все же был найден верный USB-драйвер. Так что, не сдавайтесь сразу - убедитесь, что дрова правда те.

Comment: Очень смутно верится,что под мак нужны драйвера. Под линукс (а мак все таки ближе к нему, чем к винде) максимум что нужно было - так это udev'у подсказать, что перед ним андроид девайс (что делается прописываением одной строки в текстовом файле и перезапуском демона).